# Android Device USB Debugging asks for password that I have never set

Tags: android

Ticking on USB debugging asks me for password that I have never set before. I have reset my factory setting, hence removing all my phone data, but it is still the same.

How do I reset this password?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this password what it asks is the "Desktop backup password". You can check if you set the password from the "Developer Options" menu. But if you don't remember it either, then factory reset must help to reset this.

Comment: Factory reset does not help. I have done some research and seems like the carrier of my phone set it up. I am using Andromax Z.

Comment: The question now is... how can I hack into this? Do you know any resource or person I can contact for help?

Comment: Looks like the only possible way is to create an app that can crack the phone. As usb debugging is not enabled, it is not possible to access it from computer. So much for trying to test html on mobile :/

Comment: @jaycode do you have any more info on how you would create the app to crack the phone?